# ESXI 6.5 copy paste - remote guest

Tags: vmware, remote, copy-paste

I am connected to my **remote ESXI server** via Workstation 14. From this remote connection I have a console window open for VM test. The issue is I cannot copy and paste from my local system(Windows 10) to VM console windows via remote server connection on Windows 14.

Same issue of not being able to copy and past from vsphere web console via firefox.

ESXI 6.5
Using workstation 14

Any help?

Comment: do you have VMware tools installed? because I can copy and paste just fine

Comment: Yes to VMware Tools. In fact Reinstall VMware tools is greyed out. You can copy and paste into a remote VM(NOT LOCAL) via remote esxi connection in Workstation 14? No issues if the VM is on workstation 14.  The VM is hosted on a ESXI server.